# Change string including "T07:57:00Z" to a datetime type?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a list of strings which take the following form: "2019-03-05T07:57:00Z" and I need to convert them to a Date data type so that I can do calculations with them, however I can't get R to recognize the "T07:57:00Z" as a time. The format itself doesn't matter as long as it is in a form where I can do calculations, does R have a way to handle this form of date?

Comment: FWIW this is called ISO 8601 format. Are there milliseconds in your data? If not just using `format = '%FT%TZ'` will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lubridate` for datetime use cases:

```
lubridate::ymd_hms("2019-03-05T07:57:00Z")
[1] "2019-03-05 07:57:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with base `R`

```
(res <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-05T07:57:00Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
# [1] "2019-03-05 07:57:00 CET"
```